# How can I identify a pure cotton cloth?

Tags: clothing, comfort, shopping

Yesterday, i went to shop but all of the shirts of that shop was labelled with 100% cotton tag. But It don't seem to be truly 100% cotton if i touch them.

Comment: One thing worth remembering is that pure cotton has many forms. Depending upon the thickness and the type of weave, the properties of the resulting fabric may be very different. I have some 100% cotton t-shirts that are little better than nylon to wear. My assumption is that cotton really only has the properties we like when the weave is looser and allows the fabric to absorb sweat. If they twist the fibres too tight, the result will be a thinner fabric with less ability to "wick" sweat.

Answer (score 7):

Simple technique to test natural fibers like cotton and silk against synthetic.

Find a thread of the cloth sticking out and using a lighter, burn the end. If it burns to ashes, its is natural. If on the other hand it 'melts', it is plastic (polyester, acrylic, etc).

It would probably be best to remove a thread and take it outside the store to a windless place ;)

Comment: In theory a good and feasible idea, but it might be difficult to obtain a fibre sample. For good quality shirts, all ends should be either inside a seem or otherwise hidden. Besides, most industrial sewing threads are at least partly polyester, so using a piece of that would be useless.

Comment: True true. The only alternative (?) is to then buy the shirt promising 100% cotton, burn it, and then either buy a new one of sue the company! :D

Comment: @petergus I like the way you're thinking!